# React single page application

Tags: reactjs

I'm building single page app by react but it still reloading as multipages. Mya I know what's the difference in structure betweeen both?

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div  >
        <NavbarPage />
        <Route path='/' exact component={HomePage} />
        <Route path='/about' component={AboutPage} />
        <Route path='/work' component={WorkPage} />
        <Route path='/projects' component={Projects} />
        <Route path='/contact' component={ContactPage} />
        <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
//index component 
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import './styles/styles.scss';
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter >
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root'));


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Include the link that you're using. You should use `NavLink` component and not anchor `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use link from Router. You probably have used anchor tag which is leading you to this issue

Answer (score 1):

Your app is a React single page application.

A multipage application would mean when you visit each of of your paths (
/work/, /projects/) it would load a new page to render.

React-Router allows you to declare these routes as components, without having to reload the entire app when you navigate to a new page.

It's possible you have not refactored your navigation bar to make use of React Router.

```html
HTML Navigation Bar with href links:

<a href="/work/">Work</a>
<a href="/about/">About</a>

React Router Navigational Bar:

<NavLink exact to="/work">Work</NavLink>
<NavLink exact to="/about">About</NavLink>
```

Comment: so why it's reloading in the tab name ? and it doesn't do this in the address bar.

Comment: What do you mean "reloading in the tab name"?

Comment: My guess is your Navbar looks something like
<a href="/work/">Work</a>
<a href="/about/">About</a>
You need to change it to 
<NavLink exact to="/work">Work</NavLink>
<NavLink exact to="/about">About</NavLink>